# Use dplyr to select cells from columns that contain string

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
column_a   column_b   column_c   index
346:3      BHJK       NA         1
BGH        784:2      NA         2
UBDI       SDR        NA         3
BHJD       BJS        256:1      4
```

And I would like to create a new data frame that only contains the index and the values that contain a colon (but not dropping those without it), like this:

```
index   value
1       346:3
2       784:2
3       NA
4       256:1
```

I have tried a few different ways but none have worked, including an ifelse grepl for containing ":". This is what I currently have, but it only returns the index:

```
DF_new <- DF %>% group_by(index) %>% select(contains(":"))
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `dplyr::select()` is for selecting columns. To "select cells from columns" (which really means to select rows) you use `dplyr::filter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way which kind of works is:

- pivot to have all `value`s in one column
- filter this column
- reattach to the full list of indexes

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
      ~ column_a,  ~ column_b,    ~ column_c,  ~ index,
        "346:3",     "BHJK",        NA,          1, 
        "BGH",       "784:2",       NA,          2, 
        "UBDI",      "SDR",         NA,          3, 
        "BHJD",      "BJS",         "256:1",     4)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(-index, names_to = NULL, values_to = "value") |> 
  filter(str_detect(value, ":")) |> 
  right_join(df |> select(index), by = "index")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   index value
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 346:3
#> 2     2 784:2
#> 3     4 256:1
#> 4     3 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `dplyr` only solution using `coalesce`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-index, ~ifelse(grepl("\\:", .), ., NA))) %>% 
  mutate(value = coalesce(column_a, column_b, column_c), .keep = "unused")
```

```
index value
  <int> <chr>
1     1 346:3
2     2 784:2
3     3 <NA> 
4     4 256:1
```